# Android Studio Get error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype After Add Check Internet Connections Code

Tags: android, android-studio

I just newbie in Android Studio and I want to check the internet connection, but I keep getting this error:

> method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

After Add Check Internet Connections Code.

Full Code:

```
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("this is my url");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        **@Override
        public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }**
    });


}
}
```

I Just add this code, then get error:

```
@Override
        public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Thanks for your helps...

Answer (score 0):

Setting `@Override` for `isNetworkAvailable()` means you are trying to override a method from `WebViewClient`. But there is no method `isNetworkAvailale()` in `WebViewClient`. That's why you are getting the error.

Remove the `@Override` which is on top of `isNetworkAvailable()` as follows:

```
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Remember to add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

BTW it is not a great idea to put `isNetworkAvailable()` inside `WebViewClient`. Either put it directly under `MainActivity` or create another class (lets say `DeviceUtil`). If you create a new `DeviceUtil` class, then the code will be reusable in different activities.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("this is my url");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
}


    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```